# How to fixed this error -> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input In Fetch Api

Tags: javascript, json, api, promise, asynchronous-javascript

I am calling this function on button click.
I have added a header in my API still it shows an error.

let getData = () => {
console.log("getData function started");

```
        const options = {
            method: "GET",
            headers: new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json' }),
            mode: 'no-cors'
        };
        fetch("http://167.71.226.242/", options).then((response) => {

            console.log("Inside 1st then");
            return response.json();
        }).then((data) => {
            console.log("Inside 2nd then");

            console.log(data);
        });


    }
```

Comment: It's possible your server is not returning JSON. What does logging "response" inside the first .then() give you? There you'll have the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var requestOptions = {
   'content-type': 'application/json',
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'follow'
  };
fetch("http://167.71.226.242", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

This code work. you don't use new Header(...) in options!
Read more about fetch()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time and for helping me.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible you'll just want to do this and also use the correct header name as yours is lowercase:

```
fetch('/', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
}).then(...);
```

It doesn't look like you need to use `new Headers();` as well.

You may also not need `mode: 'no-cors'` but that's your call :)